# Iterate through scrollView and find the clicked imageView

Tags: swift, imageview, scrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an horizontal scrollable ScrollView which has a lot of imageViews. I want to highlight the imageView a user has clicked on but I´m not sure how to do this. I have added a tap gesture to the image:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imgTapped(_:)))
```

But I´m not ure what to do in the `imgTapped` function from here... I have a unique tag for each imageView.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a collection of all your `imageViews` you could do something like this:

```
func imgTapped(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // get the tag for the clicked imageView
    guard let tag = sender.view?.tag else { return }

    let imageView = ImageViews.filter { $0.tag == tag }.first
}
```

Otherwise you can iterate through your `scrollViews subviews`, checkout the comments and see what happens in the code:

```
func imgTapped(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // get the tag for the clicked imageView
    guard let tag = sender.view?.tag else { return }

    // iterate through your scrollViews subviews
    // and check if it´s an imageView
    for case let imageView as UIImageView in self.imageScrollView.subviews {
        // check if the tag matches the clicked tag
        if imageView.tag == tag {
            // this is the tag the user has clicked on
            // highlight it here
        }
    }
}
```